# $f(z)$ is analytic if and only if $f(z)$ cannot be written as function of $\bar z$ ( where $z\in\mathbb C$ and $\bar z$ is conjugate of $z$)

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Maybe I understand it wrong. I don't feel relax if I don't ask this question.

I study complex analysis myself.

In the nptel's video(given below), Prof. V. Balakrishnan says that If a function of $z=x+iy$ is not function of $\bar z=x-iy$ then it is an analytical function. Moreover, at the beginning of the video he mentions about linear independence of $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z=x-iy$. And at about 22th minute of the video he writes $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$ and he concludes the Cauchy-Riemann conditions for a function to be differentiable.

**Question:**
1) What is relationship between linearly independence and derivation?
I mean how generally can we talk about differentiable of something with respect to something. In this example we can directly say the below(question 2) that to be zero. I want to understand when I can do it.

2) What come that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$ I attempted to show this by using chain rule but I couldnot finish this $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial  (x-iy)}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial (x-iy)}$$

---

Note:
He uses $z^*=x-iy$ instead of $\bar z=x-iy$

The video:https://youtu.be/b5VUnapu-qs?t=21m32s

Comment: Well, $f(z):=\overline z / |\overline z|^2$ happens to be analytic (away from $0$)

Comment: thanks for the counterexample, I think I didnot understand something like $\partial(f_1+f_2)/\partial f_1$. How can I sure that the outcome is just $1$ and inside $f_2$ there  is no function of $f_1$ and the relation between this and independence of $ f_1, f_2 $

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives)  is $$
{\partial\over\partial\overline{z}}=\frac12\left({\partial\over\partial x}+i{\partial\over\partial y}\right)
$$
This is just a formal definition of a differential operator.  If $f$ is an analytic function, you can check that the condition $$
{\partial f\over\partial\overline{z}}=0$$ is equivalent to the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Similarly, with the formal definition $$
{\partial\over\partial z}=\frac12\left({\partial\over\partial x}-i{\partial\over\partial y}\right)$$

you can check that $$
{\partial f\over\partial z}=f'(z)$$

This is sometimes expressed by saying that and analytic function $f$ is a function of $z$ alone, not of $\overline{z},$ but this is just an informal statement.  Obviously, $z$ and $\overline{z}$ are not independent variables, and it makes no real sense to talk about partial derivatives with respect to them.

Comment: I understand but "This is just a formal definition of a differential operator. If f is an analytic function, you can check that the condition ${\partial f\over\partial\overline{z}}=0$"  Why this partial derivative has to equal to 0?

Comment: It's equivalent the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  Write $f = u+iv$ and and check that ${\partial f\over\partial\overline{z}}=0$ says exactly the same thing as the Cauchy-Riemann equations.